# zsh - How do I prepend a string to every element of an array?

Tags: zsh

Say I have a zsh array `ARRAY=(a b c)`,

and want to prepend `my_` before every element in the array to get `(my_a my_b my_c)`,

how do I do that?

Comment: Similar (duplicate?): [Prepend and append a string to each element of $\* in shell](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/599771)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few options:

Using the `^` operator which is intended for that (reminiscent of `rc`'s `^`):

```
ARRAY=(my_$^ARRAY)
```

Or to make that kind of expansion the default (in the style of `rc` or `fish`):

```
set -o rcexpandparam
ARRAY=(my_$ARRAY)
```

Or the ksh93 way¹, using `${param/pattern/replacement}` with `#` as the beginning of subject anchor.

```
ARRAY=(${ARRAY/#/my_})
```

Or the csh way, but with a `histsubstpattern` twist to allow the substitution to be based on a pattern:

```
set -o histsubstpattern
ARRAY=(${ARRAY:s/#/my_})
```

Or using `printf`:

```
printf -v ARRAY my_%s "$ARRAY[@]"
```

---

<sup>¹ Technically, in ksh93 (or bash or mksh which eventually copied it as well), that would have to be `ARRAY=("${ARRAY[@]/#/my_}")` as `$ARRAY` is `${ARRAY[0]}` there and is subject to split+glob when unquoted.</sup>

Comment: @Gairfowl, d'oh. Thanks. Fixed now.

Comment: Is there a way to do something like this, but process the elements of the array via a command instead of a simple regex substitution?

Comment: @minseong, you could do something like `set -o extendedglob; ARRAY=( ${ARRAY/(#m)*/$(cmd -- $MATCH)} )`. In any case note that those *pattern* are not regexps, but globbing patterns.